# Docusign clickwrap accepted consent accepted document not getting in response

Tags: docusignapi

"accountId": "978c5351-c8d4-4f5d-bc95-15ebf0d5648d",
            "clickwrapId": "a1aaa400-a97e-4710-9a6b-ae35bcfdd2a1",
            "clientUserId": "Email: manish@jo.10, Application Name: ",
            "agreementId": "a7a23851-a6e0-4c6e-b3dc-06c9c82592bb",
            "documents": [],
            "createdOn": "2020-05-22T06:36:46.0084121Z",
            "agreedOn": "2020-05-22T06:36:50.1490267Z",
            "status": "agreed",
            "versionId": "ba004a16-78d6-462f-bcdf-c39486fef49a",
            "versionNumber": 7,
            "settings": {
                "hasDeclineButton": false,
                "actionButtonAlignment": "left",
                "mustRead": false,
                "mustView": false,
                "requireAccept": false,
                "downloadable": true,
                "sendToEmail": false,
                "format": "modal",
                "documentDisplay": "document"
            }

Comment: Answered below. If it helps you out, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks! –

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to retrieve the agreements from an existing clickwrap. You can do so by making the following request

```
GET /v1/accounts/{accountId}/clickwraps/{clickwrapId}/users
```

Response should contain:

```
{
   "200":{
      "description":"Successful response.",
      "schema":{
         "beginCreatedOn":{
            "description":"user agreements from this datetime",
            "type":"datetime"
         },
         ...
         "userAgreements":{
            "description":"array of the user agreements",
            "type":"array",
            "items":userAgreement
         }
      },
      "400":{
         "description":"Error encountered.",
         "schema":errorDetails
      }
   }
}
```